# Draggable with shift key doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have this HTML5 very simple draggable example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sqrbnaqw/

```
<div draggable="true">
  parent
  <div>
    <div draggable="true">
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you drag the word 'parent' or 'child', you'll see that you can drag it. But, if you hold the shift key, you cannot. This used to work, and works in all other browsers. Does anyone know why it doesn't in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out after this appears to be a bug in Chrome...

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=646339

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389012/cannot-perform-shift-drag-on-a-div-element-containing-an-embedded-svg-image