# Cannot perform Shift + Drag on a div element containing an embedded SVG image

Tags: javascript, svg, drag-and-drop

I have a draggable div containing an en embedded SVG image like this:

```
<div draggable="true">
  <svg width="160" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
      <text x="26.5" y="15" style="font-size: 20px;">Drag me</text>
    </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

I can drag the div, I can do Alt + Drag but when I perform a Shift + Drag nothing happens, apparently the drag start event is not invoked at all. How can I make Shift + Drag work?

Please note that the bug mentioned here: [Draggable with shift key doesn't work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184454/draggable-with-shift-key-doesnt-work-in-chrome) appears to be fixed in the latest version of Chrome while the problem I mention still occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draggable with shift key doesn't work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184454/draggable-with-shift-key-doesnt-work-in-chrome)

Comment: I have tried on the latest version of Chrome. The bug you mention seems to be fixed, however the problem I raised still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chromium, Firefox works fine

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=982219

  - You can not start a `Shift-Drag` operation if the Element has Nodes, other then text
  - If you start the drag with one click, you *can* add the `shift` key during the drag
  - If you click a "root" `Textnode` first, you *can*
    start dragging with the shift key down
    (click on the word 'tag' in the items below in the SO snippet)

If dragging SVGs is your objective, do read: https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/

```html
<script>
  function initDrag(tag, html = 'No HTML content') {
    document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement(tag),{
      innerHTML : `tag:${tag} ` + html,
      ondrag : evt => LOG.innerHTML = `Shift ${evt.shiftKey?"On":"Off"} `
    })).setAttribute("draggable", "true");
  }

  let htmlContent = `<b style="color:red;font-size:20px">with HTML content</b>`;

  initDrag("h3");
  initDrag("h3", htmlContent);
  initDrag("div");
  initDrag("div", htmlContent);
</script>

<h2 id="LOG" style="background:lightgreen">[shift key state]</h2>
```